# TypeError thrown by setInterval using node.js's

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, setinterval

I am new to NodeJS, I have a microservice running which I want to open a webpage without a browser, to make client side api requests every 20 seconds. I am attempting to use the package openurl

```
const openPage = require("openurl");

function openUpPage(url){
  openPage.open(url);
}

setInterval(openUpPage("myURl"), 20000);
```

However I am being returned "TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function" when calling `setInterval(...)`.

Any idea how I accomplish this using setInterval?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? I assume inside of the `openUpPage` function?

Comment: You are executing `openUpPage("myURl")` and setting what it returns to setInterval. Since it does not return anything your call is basically.  `setInterval(undefined, 20000);` Not related to the problem, but your code will not run on an interval.

Comment: @Luca The ```open``` implementation within the ```openurl``` package states that the callback is optional. So I assumed the error occurs at ```setInverval```.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to `setInterval` instead of calling your function right away using an anonymous arrow function as an example.

```
setInterval(() => openUpPage("myURl"), 20000);
```

The arrow function isn't a must have though.

```
setInterval(function() { openUpPage("myURl") }, 20000);
```

When testing I figured out the error `"TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function"` thrown by `setInverval` is related to node.js. The code snippet from the question runs without any errors within codepen (using Chrome).

This is caused because of the fact that pure javascript can't implement such timer-related functions due to the lack of low level support. Therefore browsers and node.js not necessarily share the same implementation as seen in the docs.

- [Node implementation](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html)
- [Common browser implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Even though calling the function right away as seen in the questions snippet is pointless in combination with `setInterval` no matter the implementation.

Comment: @epascarello Based on the posted snippet ```setInterval``` is the only call that can cause this error, no? The ```open``` implementation within the ```openurl``` package states that the callback is optional. Edit: Initial comment removed!

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply I have tried your code but I am still receiving the 
                                                                                                                            error            events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT
 at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: @Daniel Looks like something caused by node.js's ```child_process``` package. Without any code it is hard to tell what is the cause. But it doesn't look like ```setInterval``` is the problem with this. So I think the initial question was solved therefore you should create another question.